# Vue component is not reactive

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

My issue is that when i make a request to delete an item from my component, the component does not automatically update to show new state.

**template**

```
     <div v-for="house in allHouses" :key="house.id" >
       <div class="edit-delete-wrap" v-if="house.madeByMe">
       <img class="edit-delete-btn" src="/images/edit.png" alt="">
       <img @click="deleteHouse(house.id)"  class="edit-delete- 
           btn" src="/images/delete.png" alt="" srcset="">
       </div>
        {{house.street}}
     </div>
```

this is an example of the template, it is card with a house details on it, there is a button to delete this item from the list.

**Scripts for house card component**

```
<script>
import {mapActions, mapGetters} from 'vuex'
export default {
    name: "HouseCard",
    props: ["searchHouses", "sortHouses"],
    computed: {
    ...mapGetters(['allHouses']),
   
    },
    methods: {
 ...mapActions(['fetchHouses', 'houseDetail', 'deleteHouse']),
    },
    created(){
    this.fetchHouses()
  },

}
</script>
```

The list data comes from the `allHouses` houses computed function.

**vuex store**

```
import api from "../../api/houses";

const state = {
  houses: [],
  selectedHouse: [],
};

const getters = {
  allHouses: (state) => state.houses,
  selectedHouse: (state) => state.selectedHouse,
};

const actions = {
  async fetchHouses({ commit }) {
    const response = await api.fetchHouses();
    commit("setHouses", response.data);
    console.log(response.data);
  },
  createNewHouse(_, formData) {
    api.createNewHouse(formData);
  },
  async deleteHouse(_, house) {
    api.deleteHouse(house)
    const response = await api.fetchHouses();
    commit("setHouses", response.data);
  },
  async houseDetail({ commit }, id) {
    const response = await api.fetchHouses();

    response.data.forEach((house) => {
      if (house.id === id) {
        console.log(house);
        commit("setSelectedHouse", house);
      }
    });
  },
};

const mutations = {
  setHouses: (state, houses) => {
    state.houses = houses;
  },
  setSelectedHouse: (state, selectedHouse) => {
    state.selectedHouse = selectedHouse;
  },
};

export default {
  state,
  getters,
  actions,
  mutations,
};
```

here is the store where i have the manage the state of the app, in the `deleteHouse` action function i delete the house then try to get a new api response and set the state of `houses` to the new updated state of the houses array.

**api**

```
import axios from "axios";

const API_KEY = "xxxxxxxxx";

export default {
  fetchHouses() {
    return axios.get("https://api.intern.d-tt.nl/api/houses", {
      headers: {
        "X-Api-Key": API_KEY,
      },
    });
  },
  async deleteHouse(id) {
    axios
      .delete(`https://api.intern.d-tt.nl/api/houses/${id}`, {
        headers: {
          "X-Api-Key": API_KEY,
        },
      })
      .then(() => {
        console.log("successful deletion");
      });
  },
  createNewHouse(formData) {
    console.log("api page", formData);
    const image = formData.houseImage;

    return axios
      .post("https://api.intern.d-tt.nl/api/houses", formData.form, {
        headers: {
          "X-Api-Key": API_KEY,
        },
      })
      .then((res) => {
        console.log("REACHED FIRST POST");
        const id = res.data.id;
        const formData = new FormData();

        formData.append("image", image[0]);
        axios
          .post(
            `https://api.intern.d-tt.nl/api/houses/${id}/upload`,
            formData,
            {
              headers: {
                "X-Api-Key": API_KEY,
              },
            }
          )
          .then(console.log("success"))
          .catch((err) => console.log(err));
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  },
};
```

here is the api file that i use to make all api requests. i hope this information helps.

Comment: Try to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). There is not enough information here to provide a definitive answer [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

Per @RenauldC5, you didn't provide enough information about your allHouses getter or where and how the data gets into the store or where `setHouses` stores the data, and how.

However a question/tips to guide you:

1. `#setHouses` - I presume your api returns an array .. (?) So make sure you initialize the property (key) in the store (at whatever key `#setHouses` stores this array) at instantiation so that the store and Vue instances that use the `allHouses` getter know to watch that array property
2. `#deleteHouses` - When you delete the array, you seem to return a new array from the api. If this is true, simply setting the new non-reactive array overtop of the old reactive one will create an unreactive condition. This is a fundamental understanding of [Vue's reactivity system](https://vuejs.org/guide/extras/reactivity-in-depth.html) - and is likely the cause of your problem.

Fixes:

1. Whatever key `#setHouses` uses to set data on the Vuex store, instantiate it as an empty array when the store is created.
2. `#setHouses` must iterate `response.data` and `array.push(item)` onto this reactive array, rather than simply replace the reactive array with a new (non-reactive) array.
3. `#deleteHouse` - should first use `array.splice(0)` to remove all children in the reactive array, then `setHouses` will `array.push(child)` into this reactive array

Update: including examples

```
//- update: state:
const state = {
  houses: [],
  selectedHouse: null,
};

//- update: #setHouses
  setHouses: (state, houses) => {
    // empty the previous reactive array
    state.houses.splice(0);
    // push the new houses to the original reactive array
    state.houses.push(...houses);
    // state.houses now remains bound to your getters, vue instances and remains reactive
  },
```

***Update: add examples of changes***

```
//- update:state
const state = {
  houses: [],
  selectedHouse: null,
};

//- update:#setHouses
  setHouses: (state, houses) => {
    // empty the previous reactive array
    state.houses.splice(0);
    // push the new houses to the original reactive array
    state.houses.push(...houses);
    // state.houses now remains bound to your getters, vue instances and remains reactive
  },
```

PS: maybe I'm not clear on what your action #houseDetail does but it seems to re-load ALL houses ... perhaps this is what you want (?)

Comment: Thanks for your response, i am not 100% what you mean however i have provided more details above an i hope it helps.

Comment: If you read up on on Vue's reactivity - the link was in my answer - you'll see that you cannot replace the original array in the store at `state.houses` which you DO when you return the array from the action `#deleteHouse`. Per my answer, you should empty this existing array (using splice, per my answer) and then push new items from response.data onto the existing array. I imagine this is the crux of your issue.

Comment: Also note: you initialize `state.selectedHouse` as an array, but you overwrite this with a 'house' later in `#setSelectedHouse`, which is presumably an object.

Comment: Thanks again for your response, would it be possible to provide an example of the array update? i guess i understood the commit method used in the vuex store to be something used to update the state when you need to.

Comment: I updated the answer to include examples. In response to commit updating the store - yes it does, but only within the limits of Javascript and Vue's reactivity system. When you have a pointer to an array (eg getter, vue instance) and you replace the array at that location, the pointers pointing to that array won't re-point to the new array - they remain pointing to the previous (reactive) array.  Encourage you to re-read the Vue docs section on reactivity that I linked to before.